# Images are inconsistently rotated 90deg for no reason within unstyled <img> tags

Tags: css, image, browser, amazon-s3, rotation

I have an image hosted on Amazon S3 that is being flipped from portrait to landscape when put inside a completely unstyled `<img>` tag.

Chrome shows it as horizontal in the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQyWs.jpg

But when I open in new tab it displays as portrait. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrEBv.jpg

Results:

- `wget`: returns a vertical image.
- All Browsers inside image tag: horizontal
- Chrome, safari, FF in new tab: vertical
- IE new tab: horizontal

I cannot directly link to image samples because they are profile photos of users and confidential.

Has anyone encountered this before?  How can we identify if the true image is vertical or horizontal, and why is it being auto-rotated in some places but not others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes EXIF data will store a orientation for the picture. Some software will process this and show you the properly rotated version, while other software will ignore it and show you the picture's 'native' rotation. To add further complexity, I have found that my cell phone is less reliable in setting this orientation flag correction.

More information on the EXIF orientation flag -> http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

Online EXIF reader -> http://regex.info/exif.cgi